# "Заявка НА регистрацию Вас  в качестве" или "заявка ДЛЯ регистрации Вас"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать:
1. Подана заявка НА регистрацию Вас в качестве члена Клуба. (или)
2. Подана заявка ДЛЯ регистрации Вас в качестве члена Клуба.

Или это предложение нужно построить по-другому?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

ЗАявка НА регистрацию.

Answer (score 0):

Если написать "заявка для регистрации", то получится, что для регистрации нужна заявка, но на что-то еще, не на саму регистрацию.